# Distinct value from multiple tables with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct, union

So I have this mysql statement and I want to get the value of id just once. This is what i've tried with but it still writes the ids multiple times.

```
SELECT table1.id, table3.location FROM table1, table3

UNION

SELECT table2.id, table3.location FROM table2, table3

GROUP BY id
```

It gives example:

```
1 - swe
1 - swe
2 - uk
2 - uk
etc
```

I want:

```
1 - swe
2 - uk
```

Any suggestions anyone? Greatful for any help! Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is only the values on your sql? Because UNION already does the distinct unless you use UNION ALL

Comment: `GROUP BY id, location` would help

Comment: There is no aggregation function therefore no need for group by at all.

Comment: Why are you cross joining with the other tables?

Comment: Well i have more values of table 1 and 2. They are the same columns in both tables. No I use UNION :) @JorgeCampos

Comment: @PeterP Then there is more different values. And thats because your are not getting the distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the group by:

```
SELECT table1.id, table3.location FROM table1, table3
UNION
SELECT table2.id, table3.location FROM table2, table3
```

As pointed out by W3C, UNION already shows only distinctive values by default:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 1):

You no need to add group by clause cause UNION will already distinct your 2 result sets.

```
SELECT table1.id, table3.location FROM table1, table3
UNION
SELECT table2.id, table3.location FROM table2, table3
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f081b8/1)**

Comment: same answer as mine, except for the fiddle demo. :P
+1 for fiddle, thou.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.id, t3.location FROM table1 t1 
inner join  table3 t3 on (t1.id = t3.id)

UNION

SELECT t2.id, t3.location FROM table2 t2 
inner join  table3 t3 on(t2.id = t3.id)

Group by 1;